# Is there any option for SharePoint global navigation which is compatible with SharePoint Server 2013 and SharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-framework, global-navigation, modern

I'm currently using SharePoint 2013 and want to build a custom global navigation for the whole farm which is also migratable to SharePoint Online. In SharePoint Online i use the modern environment. The masterpages or composed looks aren't available in that kind of SharePoint Online and the Framework doesn't work with 2013. Is there another option for a global navigation which is working for both variants of SharePoint?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

If the custom global navigation you are looking to build is built using server side code (farm solution), then the answer is no. You cannot deploy server side solutions to SharePoint Online. You can however create SPFx extensions to create your own custom navigation. I would however recommend using the out-of-the-box hub and site navigation features for SharePoint Online. There is also a global navigation feature which will be released to SharePoint Online very soon.